# MySQL Joins with a banned words table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables:

- word: id_word, word (1, "arc" / 2, "zoo")
- definition: id_definition, id_word, data (1, 1, "any unbroken part of the circumference of a circle")
- error: id_error, word (1, "ark")

The php script throws the definition for found words. To get that definition I use:

```
SELECT word.id_word,definition.data,definition.extra
FROM word LEFT OUTER JOIN definition ON word.id_word = definition.id_word
WHERE word.lang="en" AND word.word="arc"
```

Currently, when a word does not exist in my table, i call an external api and store the request-result into the table.

To avoid constant failed request to that api, i've set an **error** table. It holds all the new non-existant words that users search (through the external api). To avoid repeated innecesary requests to the external api, i also need to previously check whether the word exists or not in the error table. If it exists, it means that somebody already tried to search for a non-existant word in the past; and instead of searching for it again in the api (i have limited requests per day) i can simply print an error: "this word does not mean anything".

How can I check if the word exists in the error table in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT w.id_word, d.data, d.extra, false as is_error
FROM word w
LEFT JOIN definition d ON d.id_word = w.id_word
WHERE w.lang="en"
AND w.word="arc"
UNION
SELECT id_error, word, null, true
FROM error
WHERE lang="en"
AND word="arc";
```

This will return:

- no rows for a completely unknown word
- one row for an error word, with the `is_error` column `true`
- one row for a known row, with the `is_error` column `false`

Comment: it is not returning the is_error=true when the word is in the error table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using the id_word and id_error to join your word table and error table you could do something like this.

```
SELECT word.id_word,definition.data,definition.extra 
  FROM word 
  INNER JOIN error ON error.word = word.word
  LEFT OUTER JOIN definition ON word.id_word = definition.id_word 
  WHERE word.lang="en" AND word.word="arc"
```

If the id_word and id_error aren't the same then you'll need to modify the SQL to use the joining column.

EDIT: I've modified the SQL to join the error table on the word table by word, I would recommend adding the word_id to the error table so you have a better join.

Comment: id_error and id_word are not linked in any way for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

When the word is present in the error table

```
SELECT W.id_word,D.data,D.extra  
FROM
(
    SELECT WK.id_word FROM
    (SELECT id_word FROM word WHERE lang='en' AND word='arc') WK
    INNER JOIN word USING (id_word)
    LEFT JOIN error E ON word.word = E.word
    WHERE E.word IS NOT NULL
) W
INNER JOIN definition D USING (id_word);
```

When the word is not present in the error table

```
SELECT W.id_word,D.data,D.extra  
FROM
(
    SELECT WK.id_word FROM
    (SELECT id_word FROM word WHERE lang='en' AND word='arc') WK
    INNER JOIN word USING (id_word)
    LEFT JOIN error E ON word.word = E.word
    WHERE E.word IS NULL
) W
INNER JOIN definition D USING (id_word);
```

Comment: the problem is that it is returning an empty recordset in both cases: when the word is not yet present in the word table, and also when the word is already present in the error table. How could I know the difference between both results? (also, it should be W.id_word instead of WW.id_word)

Comment: also you are assuming that id_error and id_word are linked, that is not the case.